# How to add spaces in a string

Tags: python

I am using the python module, markovify. I want to make new words instead of making new sentences.

How can I make a function return an output like this?

```
spacer('Hello, world!') # Should return 'H e l l o ,   w o r l d !'
```

I tried the following,

```
def spacer(text):
  for i in text:
    text = text.replace(i, i + ' ')
  return text
```

but it returned, `'H  e  l     l     o   ,    w o   r l     d ! '` when I gave, `'Hello, world!'`

Comment: this text has three `L` so it will replace `L` three times and this makes problem. You would have to get unique chars using `set()` like `set(text)`

Comment: You’d be probably better off using the `markovify.Chain` class directly instead of shoehorning individual words into a sentence-based model.

Answer (score 12):

1. You can use this one.

```py
def spacer(string):
    return ' '.join(string)

print(spacer('Hello,World'))
```

2. Or You can change this into.

```py
def spacer(text):
  out = ''
  for i in text:
    out+=i+' '
  return out[:-1]

print(spacer("Hello, World"))
```

3. (If you want)
   You could make the same function into a custom spacer function,
   But here you also need to pass how many spaces(Default 1) you want in between.

```py
def spacer(string,space=1):
    return (space*' ').join(string)

print(spacer('Hello,World',space=1))
```

4. OR FOR CUSTOM SPACES.

```
 
def spacer(text,space=1):
  out = ''
  for i in text:
    out+=i+' '*space
  return out[:-(space>0) or len(out)]

print(spacer("Hello, World",space=1))
```

##### OUTPUT

```py
H e l l o ,   W o r l d
```

Comment: indeed! but try your function without it! it works---slightly better, since ram is reduced :)  (Strings are iterable in python, and `str.join()` takes any iterable.  Building and then throwing away a list doesn't help here).  Inded the *reason* `list("sha")` returns `['s', 'h', 'a']` is *because* strings are iterable---`str.join()` will iterate either in exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks so much this seems to work quite well. :)

Comment: Indeed, strings are already iterables without converting them to list.

Comment: @SharimIqbal not so much a mistake---but a very common antipattern in python for some reason.  'nearly everything is iterable' makes python rather cool.

Comment: @2e0byo The `join` method itself still builds a list anyway. And it can [*save*](https://tio.run/##bY/dCsIwDIXv@xS5azvGcAgiA59kjFK3zlXXH9oMGeKzzzpFEcxVEr5zTuJnHJzd7n1YFm28CwgYZKuMHEfXgoyAhpAIB6CSQgblJst2hHSqh6vGQYw6IuMVgVQUaHF22rJ1GTn/cm7C/2hMUO8C9JNtQVuoP675j7BJ2duXFk0RUYbktY5P5bv1Sl7SpQk4KRTrH50wyrgwM16XzQsK2iLr6e1JV/kdjjOqCDRfnQohrDRKCP7Ncp7xZXkA) memory to do it yourself!

Comment: @KellyBundy curiously that seems to be a pathological case with 3.8.  See [this github ci run](https://github.com/2e0byo/python-join-ram-usage/runs/6349366920?check_suite_focus=true) (quickest way I could think of to test against multiple pythons).  On my machine I get different first/2nd run results in the counters, without changing the fact that it's quicker without a list.  Regardless I think this is a micro optimisation, but it was very interesting all the same, thank you :) (And ty for teaching me `f"{int:,}"`, which is very neat).

Comment: @2e0byo I only see this there: "Error: The log was not found. It may have been deleted based on retention settings.". What results did you get there? And how much quicker is it "without" a list, and on what string?

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry about that, I'll put the results together in the repo.  I used the same code as you, only with slightly tweaked recording code.  The code is in the repo, which should at least not be deleted.  Thought CI runs were public, sorry.

Comment: @KellyBundy [see the repo](https://github.com/2e0byo/python-join-ram-usage).  Anyhow I got distracted with github ci, which is never as easy as I think it is.  If I'm procrastinating later I'll add timeit runs as well ;)

Comment: @2e0byo [Some benchmark results+code](https://pastebin.com/raw/293a1mUW) from me in Python 3.9.2 and 3.10.4. There are quite drastic changes, but I compiled 3.10.4 myself and I don't know whether I did it equivalently to the version that came with Debian. But the pure `join(s)` was never the fastest.

Comment: @2e0byo Oh, one more: On my Windows laptop with Python 3.10.0, for long strings I get the complete [opposite results](https://pastebin.com/raw/39GUR1J7) than on the Debian GCE instance. In particular, the `replace` solution is by far the fastest there instead of by far the slowest. I shall try with 3.10.4 later.

Comment: @KellyBundy overprocrastination: here are [some interactive graphs](https://2e0byo.github.io/python-join-ram-usage/) ;)

Takeaway: the difference is tiny (on these ubuntu runners), but it was a fun project, and I've remembered how actions works :)  However it seems to be platform/compile dependent anyhow.

Comment: @2e0byo Neat presentation, thanks. "Log" and "Linear" seem best of those options to show differences. Even better would be if it could show the relative speed of one compared to the other (i.e. y-axis would be percent, one curve would be constant 100%, and the other would be a bit below/above). Then the lines wouldn't be so almost indistinguishably close. You could even easily show all Python versions in a single graph then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244619/discussion-between-2e0byo-and-kelly-bundy).

Answer (score 6):

The simplest method is probably

```
' '.join(string)
```

Since `replace` works on *every* instance of a character, you can do

```
s = set(string)
if ' ' in s:
    string = string.replace(' ', '  ')
    s.remove(' ')
for c in s:
    string = string.replace(c, c + ' ')
if string:
    string = string[:-1]
```

The issue with your original attempt is that you have `o`x2 and `l`x3 in your string. Replacing all `'l'` with `'l '` leads to `l`   . Similarly for `o`  .

Comment: Agreed, this is the method I would personally use.

Comment: Yes, looks correct now. Though also similar to but much more complicated than AlveMonke's.

Comment: @KellyBundy. The first version is how I'd normally do it. Alve's version is quite clever and has my endorsement. The second version here is to help OP understand their own attempt. It's basically an advertisement for why not to do it that way.

Comment: Ah, ok. Hadn't noticed the similarity to the OP's (not sure I had read theirs). And yes, join is certainly the nicest way.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest answer to this question would be to use this:-

```
"Hello world".replace("", " ")[1:-1]
```

This code reads as follows:-
Replace every empty substring with a space, and then trim off the leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Not the simplest and also not the most efficient.

Comment: @LMD Definitely not the most efficient but if you're coding in python then this should be considered normal(simple in python).

Comment: @avm Yes, that is exactly what I meant by "the simplest answer".

Comment: @LMD What's more efficient?

Comment: @avm Same question to you, what's more efficient?

Comment: @KellyBundy I suppose `" ".join(str)` is more efficient

Comment: @LMD Seems unlikely, and it wasn't in my testing. For what strings?

Comment: @KellyBundy you're right, using the standard Python interpreter this is surprisingly faster

Comment: @LMD And takes [much less memory](https://tio.run/##RY7NasMwEITveorBF0nGNRWBUgx5kmCE6sitW@sHaXswpc/uKnJC97SzfDszcaOP4E@vMe374mJIBEpmss6sa5hgMsgxlnEGNxwt1HPbvjB2tTOSjWshhRwYyuT@cWiaDg0aeVHDkxoP@DMs/kFy8L7qLBmbQ8L87ScsHpe7Q1fxscSdjg9yfSaTSMgqb/x9jdZ8lXIFeLeka/WrdtaFtIlSYDygtHgSM/@50YNS3S/eNrIZvKtevdbeOKu1/E8LUch9/wM).

Comment: @KellyBundy [this](https://tio.run/##RY/NasQgFEbX9Slu3SQGGyoDpQRmP2/QxRDEJjedUP9QZxFKnz01MW1diZ7vO/f6Jd2cPb36sK6z8S4kSEENaJTWbgAVIRlCIpyhUhU0IJ6b5oWQEScI6HUma9YRyCe2vw@UcqBA2VV0T6IvcMzl@o@dXIABZgv0gtkDby7o8ZGWzwcfZpvqgQPa8bwVEbIFprvdM9fDw4/SPo91KtFk2phUSDUrmpw4rh7VZ14iAx@Y5L7iKA0aF5Y6D9oXaBdP1ddGd0Lwb3hfEkao@N7VSmmVQSnZv835mq3rDw) is probably more efficient and I think it can further be improved.

Comment: @avm That does something different.

Answer (score 3):

```
print(" ".join('Hello, world!'))
```

Output

```
H e l l o ,   w o r l d !
```

Comment: Literally a duplicate of MadPhysicist's answer

Comment: I didn't peek. If that's what you mean.

Comment: Given the simplicity of the problem, I believe you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist if you look at the other answers, there will also be duplicates. It is unclear why I was selectively voted minus because of this.

Comment: Sorry. Knee-jerk response :)